# How To Post A Message On Behalf Of The User In Microsoft Teams App?

Tags: botframework

I'm working on an integration between Microsoft Teams and Slack.

I'm building a Microsoft Teams application which is connected to a Microsoft Bot.

Additionally, I created a server for:

1. Listening to messages which were sent by users in Slack (via Slack webhooks)
2. Posting them in Microsoft Teams conversation as a user message to the bot (outgoing message)

I receive messages from Slack (which were sent by a Slack user) to my server and I wish to post them in Microsoft Teams as messages from the user to the bot and I'm not able to do so.

I'm able to send messages from Bot to user in Microsoft Teams app via Microsoft Bot's "botbuilder" Node.js SDK:

```
session.send(message);
```

How can I send the message on the other direction (from user to bot)?

Comment: Did you find my answer sufficient? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58691032/how-to-send-private-message-in-microsoft-teams-using-bot-on-behalf-of-user-in-te) for more info, but the short version is:

- The BotFramework has no direct way to do this.
- Even the Teams Graph API doesn't currently support this. They're working on it, but don't have an ETA.

The closest thing to a workaround would be:

1. User writes message in Slack to Bot
2. Bot receives message and posts a proactive message in Teams, something like:

> User @louis1600 said: "blah blah blah"

**Resources:**

- [Proactive Messages in Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496329/proactive-messaging-bot-in-teams-without-mentioning-the-bot-beforehand/57499608#57499608)
- [@mention-ing users in Teams with a Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55968527/ms-enterprise-bot-v4-how-to-exactly-do-a-user-mention-programatically/55974618#55974618)
- [The many other Teams Bot related questions I've answered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A10860086+teams)

Comment: Any updates on this? Cuz according to the gif in the doc, bot sends message that is no different from that user would do themselves, ie showing on the right side, with no visual indication that the message is sent by the bot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots